# Axios | Ajax | Fetch async-await JS | XMLHttpRequest | Which are the best working with PHP?

Tags: php, ajax, axios, xmlhttprequest, fetch

There are various options:

- Axios
- Ajax
- Fetch
- XMLHttpRequest

I understand they are all used to fetch data without refreshing the page, but I am confused about which would be better to work with PHP?

Comment: AJAX is what you use to make asynchronous requests and you can perform AJAX requests using Axios (which uses XMLHttpRequest) or Fetch or XMLHttpRequest itself. As a practical concern : Fetch doesn't work on IE and XMLHttpRequest is a bit low level. If you need to support IE then I suggest axios (though jQuery) is also an option  but if not then whatever floats your boat

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Underneath they are all the same technology. Those are just different interfaces to doing the same thing - making an asynchronous HTTP request to the server without refreshing the page.

PHP doesn't know - and doesn't care - which one you use to make your request. All it knows is that a request arrived. How it was generated is not something which matters to it.

That's the beauty of protocols such as HTTP - as long as both client and server understand the protocol, they don't need to care how each other is actually implemented.